# Uploading text, image and file via REST API

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, http

The problem I'am actually facing is to create audio track request and send it via REST API. It wouldn't be a problem but the data is in different formats:

1. Track info (track name, music Type, Author name etc) - text only
2. Album Cover of that track (JPG, png,etc) - image
3. Track content (mp3 format etc) - audio (binary) file

The question is: Should all that data be pushed in one request?

In my opinion, all three types of data should be pushed into three different requests and to three different endpoints but maybe there is a better way

I would be very thankful for all replies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your data model is defined in the REST service you are designing, and the functionalities you are offering.

My first idea would be to keep things separate, defining the track info as the main resource defined by its metadata, and everything else as subresources. Your endpoints could be designed as follows:

- `POST /audiotracks`: Create the audio track resource. The metadata are the content of the resource, most likely in JSON format.
- `POST /audiotracks/{trackId}/albumcover`: Post album cover file as a Base64-encoded string.
- `POST /audiotracks/{trackId}/content`: Post track content as a Base64-encoded string.
- `GET /audiotracks/{trackId}`: Fetch the audio track metadata.
- `GET /audiotracks/{trackId}/albumcover`: Fetch the album cover.
- `GET /audiotracks/{trackId}/content`: Fetch track content.
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is heavily coupled with how your API will be used and your business works. Of course a lot of solutions could be used anyway but ones will works better than others.

A flexible approach could be to define the `Track` entity with CRUD operations where `Update` will admit two modes `PUT` to update the entire content (eg. if no sound is in the request it will be removed) and `PATCH` to update partially.

More or less your API definition could follow (in a REST fashion):

- `POST /track` create a new one track, the request may or not contains all information.
- `DELETE /track/{id}`
- `PUT /track/{id}` update all track information (same as `DELETE` and `POST` again but the `{id}` remain).
- `PATCH /track/{id}` update track information, no provided information will not be removed.
- `GET /track/{id}` return the entire model.
- `GET /track/{id}/projectionX` where `projectionX` are any query/projection you need (only audio, only general information, composed/encoded audio)

But, if in your business one album cover will be reused by multiple tracks then, you should define this new entity in a similar way and change the `Track` model to contains only a reference to *"album cover"* (and not the image itself).

In this way, you can refactor all your entities with minimal changes (only the model not the API calls neither workflows).

E.g. if you define `/audiotracks/{trackId}/albumcover` a change on your datamodel relations (e.g. adding the `Album` entity) not only you must to change all datamodels but the API calls and workflows too.

Anyway, evolve your API only under new business requirements.

Comment: In this case, a track model is simple. The Album Cover is 1-to-1 Relationship with Track (there are much more entities than I mentioned but you are right with separating "shared" data to another entity) In this case, Louis answer is probably the most close to what I want to receive. Thank you :)

Comment: As I commented, I think is wrong to use `POST /audiotracks/{trackId}/albumcover` if the albumcover is a data of the same entity (`AudioTracks` in this case) you are coupling the API call structure and workflow to your datamodel representation (i.e. you are forcing to do, and to know! many calls when only one is required). IMHO.

Comment: (i.e. if tomorrow you have multiple albumcovers you MUST to change all the api calls and workflows, using my approach, only who and when want to use multiple albumcovers simply must to change whatever set the albumcover `mytrack.albumdata.cover = xxx`, no changes on calls, workflows, ...)